# On button click display datepicker after selecting date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker

How to select date when click on button and pass that date to debugger in C#?

My code is working fine but my requirement is to use a button not a text box.

When first click on button display date format and select date.

After click on particular date should trigger function.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="daily" runat="server" Text="GetDailyData" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" OnClick="submit_Click" style="margin-bottom: 0.4%;" />
```

Comment: What you mean by call debugger??

Comment: I need to pass that date to my database.....

Comment: You have to catch the datapicker event and then connect with database using ajax.

Comment: please give me code for that.... it will be very helpful for me... please its my request..........

Comment: No problem which datepicker are you using??

Comment: I have written code above for text box same one........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128462/discussion-between-vinayaka-n-and-sarath-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving solution for jQuery UI datepicker.

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date = $(this).val(); //Now you got the date
    //Connect with database using simple ajax method
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://example.com/your-web-method",
        type: "POST",
        data:{"dateValue":date},
        success: function(response){
          //your actions
       }
    });
   }
 });
```